# Python regular Expressions -- 3 adjacent digits

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will find 3 adjacent digits, and only 3.

```
s = "1234sss" = no match
x = "rrr123rrr" = match
g = fff12ggg" = no match
```

I have played around with this:

```
m = re.search(r"(\d+)","Hello1234rrr")
m.group(0)
'1234'
```

I am not sure how to just return 3 digits no more or less

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a look-arounds, like this:

```
(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)
```

This will match any sequence of 3 digits which is not preceded or followed by a digit.